# How to simulate an active button in CSS for IOS Safari?

Tags: css, ios, button, safari

How can I style a button on IOS to look like the **default active state**?

I will be using touchstart, but want the button to look like a regular button that is being pressed.

HTML:

```
<button class="active"> I am pressed </button>
```

CSS:

```
button.active{
          ??? 
}
```

Images: [image: Normal] [image: active] (sorry, they are not the exact same crop-size)

EDIT: my latest attempt is:

```
    button.active
    {
        border-radius: 12px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #888;
    }
```

It’s pretty close but the border shrinks in.
[image]

Comment: Mind sharing an image of the default active state for those of us that aren't familiar with it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, faking a second `border` using the `:before` pseudo-elements

```
.active{
    background:#e2e2e2;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:92px;
    padding:.5em;
    border:3px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius:15px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

.active:before{
    content:""; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1; 
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
    right:1px;
    bottom:1px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E3jXr/